# Dynamics 365 V9 phone call with Teams

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

A customer of mine says that when he clicks on a contact's phone number in CRM, a window appears asking how he wants to make the call. He selects Teams, but then an hourglass appears and nothing else happens, no error message.

I would like to test, but in System Settings/General, checkbox "Set the telephony provider (Select provider for Click to call)" there is only Skype or Skype for business. And when I click on a phone number,  in the customer's environment, only Skype appears: I guess that it is because I am not part of the company's Teams users. How can I check in CRM the settings of the connection with Teams? I searched a lot, but only found how to integrate CRM inside Teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a Microsoft Teams feature delivery, as currently the click-to-call feature is missing with Teams. [MS Teams uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32977114-click-to-dial)

One of the user talking about Dynamics setup in uservoice and [this community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/teams-can-t-make-calls-using-the-url-tel-protocol-clicking/m-p/278130) thread gives you more context.

Probably, once that idea is implemented, then Skype/Skype for Business maybe retired and Teams will be the only click-to-dial telephony integration for Dynamics. But not sure.

Btw, Dynamics is having a Channel Integration Framework which is more powerful and some partners already having products around that CIF.